# Javascript: How do I use Javascript var to compare as min value with input type="date" in html code?

Tags: javascript

User will input the expiry date of credit card and check with current date.

```
<html>
    <script>
        var today = new Date();
        var month = today.getMonth();
        var year = today.getFullYear();
    </script>

    <body>
          <input type="date" id="date" name="trip" value="2018-10-13" min="" max="2020-12-31" />
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Javascript [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) instance. Assuming you can ensure the user will input dates in the format `2018-10-13`, you can add a listener to detect when the user has added a date, and compare that date to today's date:

```
<script>
    document.getElementById("dateInput").addEventListener("change", function() {
        var dateEntered = new Date(input);
        console.log(dateEntered); //e.g. Fri Oct 12 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)
        var today = new Date();
        console.log(today); //e.g. Thu Oct 11 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)
        console.log(dateEntered > today); // If true, means dateEntered is after today's date, meaning the credit card has not expired.
    });
</script>
```